# What is the name of this feature in cypher that allows depth matching rules in a path match statement? Where is the documentation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having a hard time identifying the rules around this syntax, I see it and kind of understand it, but would like to find the documentation. I'm not sure how to google it though.

```
match (g:Group)<-[*1..2]-(s)
                   ^^^^
                   ^^^^ I would like to know more about this rule that limits path length
```

I understand that the above says "I only want to find paths that are between 1 and 2 edge traversals long", and it it really is that simple that's great; but I as I understand it the use of a star makes it a wildcard on which edges it can follow, while `[:EdgeTypeIWant1..2]` doesn't appear to be correct syntax. I probably have other questions as well that proper documentation (if I could find it) would be helpful with.

Comment: See: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called *variable length patterns*.

The star is only an indicator that you're specifying a pattern of variable length, it's not a wildcard.

Your syntax would be: `[:EdgeTypeIWant*1..2]`